# Java:Why the abstract class often has a static method?And the purpose of this?

Tags: java, static, abstract

I often read source codes of Java, but I found an interesting thing. Many useful class or package, for example, if I want to get a object of this, I can use a static method from an abstract class instead of new. Is there anyone tell me the purpose of[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GHCS.png) that? Thanks a lot.For example, I want to get a ByteBuff.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GHCS.png)

Comment: I don't know if it works as a duplicate, but it is worth reading in your case: [What are static factory methods?](//stackoverflow.com/q/929021)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is called static factory pattern. There are a number of reasons to do this, and these are some of the reasons that I know of:

#### Easier to read/use

Taking `java.time.Duration` as an example, you would notice that this class has a private constructor as well. You would also notice methods such as `Duration.ofDays()`, `Duration.ofHours()` and so on.

If this class is to expose its constructor (make it public), then you would expect something like:

```
public Duration(long days, long hours, long minutes, long seconds, long milliseconds, long nanoseconds)
```

Doing this would be very troublesome, because most people don't create durations like "1 days 2 hours 3 minutes, 4 seconds, 5 milliseconds and 6 nanoseconds."

#### Abstracting implementation

This is actually the main reason for `ByteBuffer` to use this approach. `ByteBuffer` itself is actually an `abstract` class. There are a number of implementing classes, but it has been hidden from its users. `ByteBuffer.allocate()` actually returns an instance of `DirectByteBuffer`, but you don't even know `DirectByteBuffer` even existed! This is because that class itself is package-private.

#### Caching

Some API may internally do some kind of caching in order not to create excessive copy of the same thing. These usually occur in immutable classes, where the value would remain unchanged. Static "creational" methods allow the class to look for a cached instance to return to the caller, instead of allowing the caller to create excessive instances of it. Another use-case would be to attempt to reuse an object which would be expensive to re-create.

#### Partially `final`

Some API may attempt to achieve something similar to `final` classes.

```
package com.test

public class Test {
    Test() { // package-private
    }

    public Test create() { return new Test(); }
}
```

This allows the API to create new classes that extends this `Test` class while blocking other people from create subclasses of `Test`. This is because subclasses outside of `com.test` package would not be able to call `super()`.

This is no longer necessary, though, after modules were introduced in Java 9.

Comment: I think your answer is very good and solve my problem by using the static factory pattern.And your answer is in detail,give you a thumb up!